# Unable to setData (of 'undefined') to allow element drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to drop an element into another element but it's not working. The errors I get are

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined`

and

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined`

with the second one depending on the first one of course.

The element I'm trying to drop looks like this:

```
<main id="post-it" class="post-it-content">
    <div class="vertical-stripes"></div>
    <div class="vertical-stripes"></div>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <span class="normal-text"></span>
            <span class="normal-text"></span>
        </li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li class="notes-footer"></li>
    </ul>
    <textarea id="notes-area"></textarea>
</main>
```

This is the yellow looking note in the picture further down.

And then I handle the drag and dropping like so:

```
var dragAndDrop = {
    allowDrop: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    drop: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    },
    drag: function(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    }
}
```

And bind the elements to the corresponding functions like this:

```
$('.post-it-content').on('dragstart', dragAndDrop.drag); //Yellow note element
li.on('drop', dragAndDrop.allowDrop);
li.on('dragover', dragAndDrop.drop);
```

Where the `li` element(s) are the square(s) in this image:

[image: example image]

Now what I'm not understanding is why I get the errors that I get, I'm doing it exactly like the example found here (although not with an image): http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop but for me it's not working. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: try doing a console.log of e.dataTransfer to see what it is

Comment: @LiamSchauerman well it's obviously undefined, but I don't understand why it's undefined.

Answer (score 2):

it’s an issue with jQuery and you can resolve it by adding the following code when the page loads or before using dataTransfer

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
```

Example:

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer'); 
event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the jQuery wrapper.We have to add 'dataTransfer' to Event object.

> Note: `$.event.props` was removed in jQuery 3.0 so you will need to use
>   `$.event.addProp` instead.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.event.addProp('dataTransfer');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error when trying to set the data like this

```
event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", nodeTitle);
```

Then I found that event doesn't have any key `dataTransfer`, instead it has the same key inside the `originalEvent`. So we can access it like below

```
event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", nodeTitle);
```